# CSS width isn't changing, no matter what I do

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

Here is the site in question:

http://harrisonfjord.com/folio/

**The Problem**

The site works fine (uses swipe.js to handle the slider), but once you resize the window lower than around 380px the whole thing breaks. (try resizing the window then going 1 or 2 slides to the right).

I can't for the life of me work out why this is. None of my media queries are affecting the window size, and it looks like the containing `<li>` elements can't go lower than 352px. If I set them to `width: 180px !important;` it still keeps them at 352px!

I'm completely stumped. Any ideas on what's causing these issues?

Comment: Use a web-browser developer tool to inspect the *applied* styles. Then play about with changing the CSS of the "live elements" (or relevant "live style selectors") and see what occurs.

Comment: That's what I've been doing, with Chrome's inspect element. I resize the browser to quite small, and play around with settings, but everything remains broken. I've even started removing most of the css I've applied but to no avail.

Comment: Are you looking at **all** (like inherited or `!important`) of the styling applied to the element, and its parents?

Comment: @Ian I am. Are you guys seeing something I'm not?

Comment: I don't see anything breaking like you say. The only thing I see not "working" is the fact that the arrows don't stay below the content after the window gets too small to hold them on the sides. Is that what you mean? The `li`s seem to resize fine for me

Comment: Yep I've done some re-coding of the swipe.js file which kinda fixed it. Guess this question is obsolete, although good to note that with swipe.js 1.0 the code was completely broken.

Answer (score 0):

The site seems to be broken completely in IE 8. Some issues with internet explorer are caused because it is in 'quirks mode' (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode). By just ensuring the doctype was set and nothing occurred before the doctype my site started working as expected.